# Not able to assign the Model to the Cache

Tags: c#, json, telerik, asp.net-mvc-4

My Code:

```
public class MyCustomGridActionResultFactory : IGridActionResultFactory
{
    public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create(object model)
    {
        ResultCache.AdvanceSearchGridResult = model as List<Models.Search.SearchGridModel>;

        //return a custom JSON result which have json serializer set to int.MaxValue
        return new CustomJsonResult
        {
            Data = model
        };
    }
}
```

Result Cache code:

```
public static class ResultCache
{
    public static List<Models.Search.SearchGridModel> AdvanceSearchGridResult
    {
        get { return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["AdvanceSearchGridResult"] as List<Models.Search.SearchGridModel>; }
        set { System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["AdvanceSearchGridResult"] = value; }
    }
}
```

**

> model as `List<Models.Search.SearchGridModel>` returns NULL value

**NOTE**:

`ResultCache.AdvanceSearchGridResult = model;` gives error message as "cannot convert from object to list"

**. How to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What's the runtime type of model? There's two possible reasons why 'as' would return null. The left hand side is null or not of the type on the right hand side.

So either you are passing null to Create or an object of another type. Debug to find out which

**EDIT**

from the comment it would seem to be option two. If the posted runtime info is the type of model, it's not a List. Try to change 'List<...>' to 'IEnumerable<...>'

```
public static IEnumerable<Models.Search.SearchGridModel> AdvanceSearchGridResult {
        get { return (IEnumerable<Models.Search.SearchGridModel>)HttpContext.Current.Session["AdvanceSearchGridResult"]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["AdvanceSearchGridResult"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to assign the json result in the datacache which is here as "ResultCache.AdvanceSearchGridResult". "model" having values but not able to assign to the cache, also not able to convert to list from the model which is an "object" type. Thanks.

Comment: [System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo] is {System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Web.Mvc.Models.Search.SearchGridModel] Take[SearchGridModel](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Web.Mvc.Models.Search.SearchGridModel], Int32)}. Thanks

Comment: Ienumerable also returns NUll. Thanks.

Comment: Well your problem is the type. Try with a regular cast (debugging information is rather helpful) once you have the right type use that for your cast

Comment: Please put a sample cast syntax. I will follow up that. Thanks